# Replacing values in multiple colums with values from the same columns in different rows, based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a solution for replacing values in multiple colums with values from the same columns in different rows, with rows selected depending on the values of other columns in the same rows.

A reduced example of my data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(
          id=c(1:7),
          set = c(1,2,2,3,1,3,2),
          choice = c("A1","A2","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2"),
          parameter1=c("blue","green","red","red","orange","blue","green"),
          parameter2=c("low", "low","high","medium","high","high","low")
          ))

data

  id set choice parameter1 parameter2
1  1   1     A1       blue        low
2  2   2     A2      green        low
3  3   2     A1        red       high
4  4   3     A1        red     medium
5  5   1     A2     orange       high
6  6   3     A2       blue       high
7  7   2     A2      green        low
```

Concretely, what I am trying to do is replacing the values of parameter 1 and parameter 2 for a set with the values of parameter 1 and parameter 2 of the same set but with the the other choice. So for the first row, set = 1 and choice = A1, I want to replace the parameter 1 and parameter 2 with the values from row 5, as this is the same set (=1) but the alternative choice (A2).

I have more parameters and sets in the full data set, so a solution should be generalizable for more parameters and choice sets. Also, if relevant, sets and corresponding choices appear multiple times, but always with the same parameter values.

I am aware that I could write all of that out with various kinds of if conditions, but that would be error prone (and not fun at all). Maybe someone has an idea on how to go about this in a smart way?

(This is my first question here, hope that makes sense and it is clear enough).

EDIT for clarification:
I am looking to replace Set 1, A2 values with Set 1, A1 values and vice versa, with the numbe of observations remaining the same. The desired result would look like this:

```
  id set choice  parameter1 parameter2
1  1   1     A1      orange       high  
2  2   2     A2         red       high
3  3   2     A1       green        low
4  4   3     A1        blue       high 
5  5   1     A2        blue        low
6  6   3     A2         red     medium
7  7   2     A2         red       high
```

Comment: And `parameter1` and `parameter2` values of row 5 should change to row 1? For more than 2 `choice` how do you decide which row values should be interchanged,

Comment: Should have clarified this. The data is from a choice experiment were participants always select one of two alternatives, thus there always are only 2 choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with your sample data and at a bigger scale. Your data :

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(
  id=c(1:7),
  set = c(1,2,2,3,1,3,2),
  choice = c("A1","A2","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2"),
  parameter1=c("blue","green","red","red","orange","blue","green"),
  parameter2=c("low", "low","high","medium","high","high","low")
),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

R code :

We first create a key in the first table by concatenating the column set and choice. According to your expectations, we create another table in which we generate a key for joining the 2 tables (we use substr and one ifelse). Then we join the two tables, keeping unique ids and removing the columns helpers.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
    data$new3=paste0(data$set,data$choice)
    df=data[,1:3]
    df$new=stri_sub(df$choice,-1,-1)
    df$new2=ifelse(df$new==1,2,1)
    df$new3=paste0(df$set,stri_sub(df$choice,1,1),df$new2)
    df %>% left_join(select(data, starts_with("parameter"),new3), by = "new3") %>% 
      distinct(id,.keep_all = TRUE) %>%
      select(-starts_with("new"))
```

Output :

```
  id set choice parameter1 parameter2
1  1   1     A1     orange       high
2  2   2     A2        red       high
3  3   2     A1      green        low
4  4   3     A1       blue       high
5  5   1     A2       blue        low
6  6   3     A2        red     medium
7  7   2     A2        red       high
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R (near solution):

```
# Take a subset of the unique ids and sets: params_inverted => data.frame
params_inverted <- unique(data[,c("set", "choice")])

# Invert the choices: levels(data$choice) => factor levels
levels(data$choice) <- rev(levels(data$choice))

# Merge with the original data.frame: params_inverted => data.frame
params_inverted <- merge(
  params_inverted,
  data[, c("set", "choice", grep("param", names(data), value = TRUE))],
  by = c("set", "choice"),
  all.x = TRUE
)
```

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(
  id=c(1:7),
  set = c(1,2,2,3,1,3,2),
  choice = c("A1","A2","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2"),
  parameter1=c("blue","green","red","red","orange","blue","green"),
  parameter2=c("low", "low","high","medium","high","high","low")
))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The code above unfortunately results in a dataset different from what I was looking for. I edited my question to include the desired result.

Comment: @JuergenF please check my edited answer. It is nearly what you want I think. If you find it useful please upvote it and if it answers your question please accept it.